# comparing blob detection and Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors in opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, blob, shapes

I need to use blob detection and Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors (more specifically `findContours`, `drawContours` and `moments`) to detect colored circles in an image. I need to know the pros and cons of each method and which method is better. Can anyone show me the differences between those 2 methods please?

Comment: It will be hard to actually specify which method will be better without seeing some **sample images**. Each method has its own vulnerabilities in some datasets with respect to the others.

Comment: Here is the image http://i.imgur.com/lDRIx6y.jpg. Which method would be best and why. I have already tried using blob with this image but due to the image quality,it does not return anything. I have successfully detected all the points with findContours and moments. Maybe I have missed something and that is why my blob detection is not working. That is why I want to know the pros and cons of both methods

Comment: Could you try something a bit simpler..? Perhaps split the color image into different channels and then do a `HoughCircles` on each channel using a low threshold while doing a pushback.

Answer (score 1):

As @scap3y suggested in the comments I'd go for a much simpler approach. What I'm always doing in these cases is something similar to this:

```
// Convert your image to HSV color space
Mat hsv;
hsv.create(originalImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
cvtColor(originalImage,hsv,CV_RGB2HSV);

// Chose the range in each of hue, saturation and value and threshold the other pixels
Mat thresholded;
uchar loH = 130, hiH = 170;
uchar loS = 40, hiS = 255;
uchar loV = 40, hiV = 255;
inRange(hsv, Scalar(loH, loS, loV), Scalar(hiH, hiS, hiV), thresholded);

// Find contours in the image (additional step could be to 
// apply morphologyEx() first)
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(thresholded,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// Draw your contours as ellipses into the original image
for(i=0;i<(int)valuable_rectangle_indices.size();i++) {
    rect=minAreaRect(contours[valuable_rectangle_indices[i]]);
    ellipse(originalImage, rect, Scalar(0,0,255));  // draw ellipse
}
```

The only thing left for you to do now is to figure out in what range your markers are in [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: thanks for suggesting other ways guys. But as long as my piece of code is working,I am fine with it. I just wanted to make a comparison between blob and structural analysis.